# How To Limit An Int To 3 Digits

Tags: java, integer

I am wondering if anyone knows how I could limit an integer to 3 digits. If the number is shorter than 3 digits, I want to output a number prepended with zeroes. If the number is longer than 3 digits, I want to output only the leading three digits.

For example:

- If a *"long"* number such as **382198** is inputted, the expected output would be **382**.
- If a *"short"* number such as **62** is inputted, the expected output would be **062**.
- If a number with *exactly 3 digits* such as **123** is inputted, the expected output would be **123**.

I have tried using DecimalFormat and StringFormat, but I did not have any success with either. I would like to avoid creating any extra objects if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example code shows how to use '/' and `System.out.printf` to obtain what you want without expensive Objects being created

```
    int val = 99;
    while (val > 1000) 
        val = val / 10;

    System.out.printf("%03d%n", val);

    val = 123456;
    while (val > 1000) 
        val = val / 10;

    System.out.printf("%03d%n", val);
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution that doesn't involve creating any extra objects. Worked well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
 public class DigitsFormatter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(limitDigits(123232)); //123
        System.out.println(limitDigits(12)); //012
    }

    public static String limitDigits(int n) {
        String str = String.valueOf(n);
        if (str.length() > 3) {
            str = str.substring(0,3);
        }
        return String.format("%03d", Integer.valueOf(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: correct but expensive, there are so many Objects being created

Comment: [@ScaryWombat's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48675642/8769017) provides a solution that avoids creating so many objects.